# How does one turn a scanf result into a NSString and then turn into a property of a class?

Tags: objective-c, class, nsstring, scanf

I need to take a scanf result and turn it into a NSString, and then the NSString into a property of instance pea1 of class Pea.
It would also be nice if I could put some kind of limit on the scanf so users didn't put too many characters in and stop the program, but this isn't absolutely necessary.

I've spent all of my freetime (six hours) trying to find this over the internet, but it doesn't work. There were a lot of results for either turning a scanf into a NSString or a NSString into a property of a class instance, but I couldn't find both and combining them didn't work.

I need this so that users can name a pea through scanf, and then have that pea's name be displayed.

Here's my code, with everything that doesn't effect this problem taken out:

```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

   @interface Pea: NSObject

   @property (retain) NSString *name;

   @end

   @implementation Pea

   @synthesize name;

   @end

   int main (int agrc, char * argv[])

   {
       @autoreleasepool {
           Pea *pea1 = [[Pea alloc] init];

           char word;

           //Asks for name of Pea
           NSLog(@"What would you like to name this pea?");
           scanf("%s", &word);

           NSString* userInput = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: &word];
           [pea1 setName: userInput];

           //NSLogs data
           NSLog (@"Your pea plant, %@\n.", [pea1 name]);

       }
       return 0;
    }
```

Thank you so much for any help you may have! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you're trying to store a string inside a single character, and that's wrong because the user may type a string longer than one character, so you have to sue an array:

```
size_t size= 100; // Arbitrary number
char word[size];
```

Then I suggest to use *fgets* instead of *scanf*, so you can limit the number of characters taken in input:

```
fgets(word,size,stdin);
```

*fgets* also appends the terminating character, but it doesn't remove the '\n' character, so in case you don't want it you have to remove it:

```
size_t length= strlen(word);
if(word[length-1] == '\n')   // In case that the input string has 99 characters plus '\n'
    word[length-1]= '\0';    // plus '\0', the '\n' isn't added and the if condition is false
```

Finally create the Objective-C string:

```
NSString* value= [NSString stringWithUTF8String: word];
pea1.name= value;
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out a lot; Also, to anyone who is having this same problem, I got an error upon execution that stopped the program (the thread breakpoint was the fgets line). However, instead of `size_t size = 100; char word[size];` I used `char word[100];` and this worked. Also, do `fgets(word, 100, stdin)` instead of the fgets line @Ramy suggested. But thank you very much!

Comment: `scanf` can also limit the number of characters, e.g. `scanf("%99s", &word);`

Comment: I don't like it because it may leave the standard input buffer dirty.

Comment: Its a little easier to read and shorter if you do ` if (word [strlen (word) - 1] == '\n') /*newline is here*/ word[strlen (word)-1] = '\0'; `

Comment: I don't like to compute the string length 3 times when I can just do it once.

Answer (score 0):

char is one symbol, maybe you mean `char *word`?

Your problem is - you scan 1 symbol, and then you use it like char string.